# Configure Azure AD as Identity provider OIC in Keycloack and email attribute

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect, keycloak

I success configuring Azure AD as identity provider using OIC in Keycloack. But it ask email during the first connection with keycloak.

And I can't find how to create the mapper to populate email in keycloack with the one of Azure AD.

I figure that it's the userprincipalname that I get the email.

So I try that without success:
[image]

Comment: The UPN claim is `upn`. With v2 endpoint of AAD, you could also require the `email` scope and get the email in `email` claim. UPN and email can be different in some cases :/

Comment: OK thank you it works using "upn".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UPN claim is `upn`. With v2 endpoint of AAD, you could also require the `email` scope and get the email in `email` claim. UPN and email can be different in some cases.

Comment: If we want o configure first name and last name, can you tell us the exact configuration to be used

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

1. You need to create a new "Flow" in Authentication tab and "Add Execution" then add the Flow : "Create User If Unique".
2. In Identity Providers tab, you need to change the "First Login Flow" option, and pick the flow you've just created.